# Running Into a Object Null Error Building Bug Tracker

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an Bug Tracker with Asp.Net following a self paced online course. I'm running into an 'Object not set to a reference error" while attemping to list out Tickets assigned to each project in my Project Details View. I know information isn't being passed in, but I'm not sure how to fix that. Any specific solutions to the problem?

**Attempted Work Arounds:**

- Commented out the Ticket Status and Ticket Priority Code and it worked, but it doesn't show everything I'd like.

*[Youtube Video of Error](https://youtu.be/JNAIqiqV3D8)*

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av95i.png)

*[Highlighted Code in GitHub Repo](https://github.com/austinbruso/TheBugTrackerProject/blob/master/Views/Projects/Details.cshtml#:%7E:text=%40if%20(ticket.TicketStatus,)%3C/td%3E)*

***Problem Code:***

```
@model TheBugTrackerProject.Models.Project
@using TheBugTrackerProject.Models.Enums
@using TheBugTrackerProject.Services.Interfaces
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using TheBugTrackerProject.Models


@inject UserManager<BTUser> userManager
@inject IBTProjectService ProjectService
@inject IBTHistoryService HistoryService

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";

    BTUser btUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    BTUser projectManager = await ProjectService.GetProjectManagerAsync(Model.Id);
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row gy-2">
            <div class="col-md-12 col">
                <div class="row col-cols-2 mt-5 bg-secondary">
                    <div class="card col m-1 p-2">
                        <div class="body">
                            @* Project Name *@
                            <h5>@Model.Name</h5>
                            @* Project Description *@
                            <p>@Model.Description</p>
                            <div class="progress-container progress-info m-b-25">
                                <span class="progress-badge" style="font-size:small">Project Status</span>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    @* Razor code block *@

                                    @{

                                        var start = Model.StartDate.DateTime;
                                        var end = Model.EndDate.DateTime;
                                        var today = DateTime.Now;
                                        var percent = today >= end ? 100 : today < start ? 0 : Math.Round((today.Subtract(start)) / (end.Subtract(start)) * 100);

                                    }

                                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: @percent;">
                                        @* Use Progress Bar code variable here *@
                                        <span class="progress-value">@percent%</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card col m-1 p-2">
                        <div class="body">
                            <ul class=" list-unstyled basic-list">
                                <li>Start Date: <span class="">@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy")</span></li>
                                <li>Deadline: <span class="">@Model.EndDate.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy")</span></li>
                                <li>Priority: <span class="">@Model.ProjectPriority?.Name</span></li>
                                @* if() logic *@
                                @if (today < end && today >= start)
                                {
                                    <li>Status:<span class="">Active</span></li>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <li>Status:<span class="">Inactive</span></li>
                                }


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col mt-5 ">
                <div class="bg-secondary">
                    <div class="card m-1 p-2">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>Project Manager</h2>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="body" style="overflow-y:auto;height:300px;">
                            @* if() logic for Avatar/Default etc *@

                            @if (projectManager != null)
                            {
                                <div>

                                    @if (projectManager.AvatarFileData != null)
                                    {
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/*;base64, @(Convert.ToBase64String(projectManager.AvatarFileData))" alt="" />
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <img class="rounded-circle " style="width: 60px; height:60px;" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/512/avatardefault_92824.png" alt="" />
                                    }
                                    <div>
                                        <h5>@projectManager.FullName</h5>
                                        <span>@projectManager.Email</span>
                                        <p class="text-muted m-b-0">Project Manager</p>
                                        @if (User.IsInRole(nameof(Roles.Admin)) || (btUser.Id == projectManager.Id))
                                        {
                                            <a class="btn btn-xs alert-primary" style="font:small;" asp-action="AssignUsers" asp-controller="Projects" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Manage Team</a>
                                        }
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            }
                            else

                            {
                                <div>
                                    <img class="rounded-circle" style="width:60px;height:60px;" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/avatardefault_92824.png" />
                                    <div class="wid-u-info">
                                        <h5 class="text-muted m-b-0">Not Assigned</h5>
                                        @if (User.IsInRole(nameof(Roles.Admin)))
                                        {
                                            <span><a asp-action="AssignProjectManager" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-info">Assign PM</a></span>
                                        }
                                        <span><a asp-action="AssignProjectManager" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-info">Assign PM</a></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col mt-5 ">
                <div class="bg-secondary">
                    <div class="card m-1 p-2">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>Project Team</h2>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="body" style="overflow-y:auto;height:300px;">
                            <ul class="right_chat list-unstyled mb-0">
                                @* Logic for avatars *@

                                @foreach (BTUser member in await ProjectService.GetAllProjectMembersExceptPMAsync(Model.Id))
                                {
                                    <li class="">
                                        <a href="">
                                            <div class="media">
                                                @if (member.AvatarFileData != null)
                                                {
                                                    <img class="" src="data:image/*;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(member.AvatarFileData))" alt="" />
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <img class="" src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/avatardefault_92824.png" />
                                                }
                                                <div class="">
                                                    <span class="">@member.FullName</span>
                                                    <span class="">@((await userManager.GetRolesAsync(member)).FirstOrDefault())</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col mt-5 ">
                <div class="bg-dark">
                    <div class="card m-1 p-2">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>Project Activity</h2>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="body" style="overflow-y:auto;height:300px;background-color:antiquewhite">
                            @* Project Activity loop *@
                            @foreach (TicketHistory history in await HistoryService.GetProjectTicketHistoryAsync(Model.Id, btUser.CompanyId.Value))

                            {
                                <div class="">
                                    <span class="date">@history.Created.ToString("dd MM, yyyy")</span>
                                    <h6>@history.Description</h6>
                                    <span>By: <a href="" title="@history.User.FullName">@history.User.FullName</a></span>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <p>The Ticket <b>@history.Property</b>  was edited</p>
                                        <p>@($"Previous {history.Property}:      {history.OldValue}")</p>
                                        <p>@($"Current {history.Property}:      {history.NewValue}")</p>

                                        <div class="media">
                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                <h6 class="mb-0"></h6>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col">
                <div class="mt-5 bg-secondary">
                    <div class="card m-1 p-2">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h2>Tickets</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-y:auto;height:600px;">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <thead class="">
                                        <tr>
                                            @* Table header *@
                                            <th>Title</th>
                                            <th>Developer</th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th>Priority</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @* Table body *@

                                        @foreach (var ticket in Model.Tickets.OrderByDescending(d => d.Created))
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Tickets" asp-route-id="@ticket.Id" style="color:black"><strong>@ticket.Title</strong></a> </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @if (ticket.DeveloperUserId != null)
                                                    {
                                                        @ticket.DeveloperUser?.FullName
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        if (User.IsInRole(nameof(Roles.Admin)) || User.IsInRole(nameof(Roles.ProjectManager)))
                                                        {
                                                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" asp-action="AssignDeveloper" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-ticketId="@ticket.Id">Assign Dev</a>
                                                        }

                                                    }
                                                </td>
                                                @if (ticket.TicketStatus.Name == "New")
                                                {
                                                    <td><span class="badge-success">@ticket.TicketStatus.Name</span></td>

                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <td><span class="badge-success">@ticket.TicketStatus.Name </span></td>
                                                }
                                                <td><span class="badge-warning">@ticket.TicketPriority.Name </span></td>
                                                <td>@ticket.Created.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info" asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Tickets" asp-route-id="@ticket.Id"><i class="fs-5 bi-justify"></i></a>
                                                    @if (ticket.DeveloperUserId == btUser.Id || ticket.OwnerUserId == btUser.Id || (projectManager?.Id == btUser.Id) || User.IsInRole(nameof(Roles.Admin)))
                                                    {
                                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Tickets" asp-route-id="@ticket.Id"><i class="fs-5 bi-pencil"></i></a>
                                                    }

                                                    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || (projectManager?.Id == btUser.Id))
                                                    {
                                                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"><i class="fs-5 bi-archive"></i></a>
                                                    }
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Thanks in advance.**

P.S. My code is a mess; but looking forward to working with other's on here and possibly in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project service, you aren't `Include`-ing the ticket status so it will be null. Try something like this instead:

```
Project project = await _context.Projects
    .Include(p => p.Tickets)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.TicketStatus) // <-- add this line
    .Include(p => p.Members)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPriority)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == projectId && p.CompanyId == companyId);
```

Comment: The 'TicketPriority' wasn't working either, so I added one for that too. Thanks for your help!